# How do you tell libgdx to use a specific color for transparency?

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx

I use GraphicsGale and it doesn't support transparency. The easy fix for this problem is to just use a really ugly color (#808040 in my case) and use that for transparency. I haven't been able to find a way how to do this in libgdx though. I can of course just pull it through GIMP and fill in the transparency, but it would be nice to work straight out of GraphicsGale.

So my question is, is there a way to make libgdx treat a color as transparency, and if there is, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modularized my approach at replacing the color with transparency, here's my ImageMagick script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf x-android/assets/*
cp -r assets/* x-android/assets

cd x-android/assets
for f in `find . -name "*.png"`
do
    convert $f -transparent '#808040' $f
done
```

Not a direct answer, but it works way better.